# Jmeter wrong password after running scripts

Tags: jmeter

I recorded login action however after recording. I run scripts again and it **told that wrong password or username**.

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: you can have login rules, as no duplicate login allowed, or maximum login per hour, check application log and add more information to question

Comment: i dont think so. cuz there is no rule of login as long as input username/password correctly. anw, thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script, modern web applications use dynamic parameters in order to establish and maintain security ([CSRF protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention)) or track user state ([VIEWSTATE](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_StateManagement.html)). So in order to be able to successfully replay the recorded script you need to implement **correlation** - detect all dynamic parameters, extract them using JMeter's [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace hard-coded recorded values with the relevant JMeter variables like:

- Open login page

  - Extract dynamic parameters values
- Perform login - send credentials and dynamic parameters

---

Another option is re-recording your request using cloud-based proxy service, it can export recorded requests in SmartJMX mode automatically detecting and handling all dynamic parameters found in the response. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details on the approach.

Comment: I found that there is 3 kind tracking user state. Do i need to extract them all?